# A good way to insert data to DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `images` (`anunt`, `image_location`) VALUES(?, ?)");

        $query->bindValue(1, $iddd);
        $query->bindValue(2, $image_location);


        try{
        $query->execute();
```

or this

```
$ret = sql_query("INSERT INTO images (anunt, image_location) VALUES ('" .$iddd. "', '" .$image_location. "')");
```

Or another way maybe?
What advantages are with the bind one? I read something that it's hard to sql inject.

Comment: Read about "sql injection".  There are a lot of resources already written on the topic.  Also, try searching SO for "bind variables sql injection".  You should find quite a few relevant answers.

Comment: Some here will argue that you should _always_ use prepared statements. I don't subscribe to that view - I believe in using the appropriate tool for the job, which isn't always prepared statements. The caveat is that prepared statements aren't susceptible to SQL injection. I argue that other methods can be secured against SQL inection too.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php. This question specifically asks for the advantages of prepared statements, which include more than SQL injection prevention

Comment: ^
Exactly, I did not ask what to do to prevent sql injection, I said that i read it's an advantage, that's what i know not what i want to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Databse pre-optimzations

When you initialize a prepared statement, the DBMS actually pre-optimizes the database and compiles your query. This would be useful if you plan to make multiple bound queries with the same prepared statement.

#### SQL Injection prevention

The PHP SQL drivers will escape any literals inside a bound value, to prevent SQL injection.